# How do I create an empty Prefab with Unity 2018.3?

Tags: unity

I was using Unity 2018.1.(something), where I could simply create an empty Prefab object, then drag a Game Object to the Prefab from the Hierarchy to fill it. When I updated to Unity 2018.3.0f2, I don't see any more empty Prefab object in the create menu, all I get is Prefab Variant (which is disabled).

I read the Unity Blog talking about new prefab workflows, and I could not find any changes in how Prefabs are created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still do it the other way around, which is: GameObject -> Create Empty. That will create an empty GameObject in your scene. You can then drag it into your Project View that will create a prefab in your project. The "Prefab Variant" selection only works when you have a prefab selected in your Project View.